# What does the word "habe" (habere) mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, verbs

I'm translating the phrase "bonum animum habe". The website that I'm using,

> [https://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=habere&form=habe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUBPF.jpg)

says that it’s an imperative present verb. But I don't know what person it is. It can't be first person, because I'm pretty sure there are no first person present imperative endings. But second person doesn't make sense in this context. Here's a sample of what I've been translating for the sake of context.

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't second person make sense in this context?

Comment: (For reference, it's second person singular. But if you tell us more about why it doesn't seem to fit as that, we can write a more useful answer.)

Comment: Achilles is directly addressing his mother in this sentence. If Achilles is the one giving the command too his mother then that wouldn't make sense because in the past three lines, she's the one who's trying to motivate him. So the sentence "O beata mater, bonum animum habe" is obviously supposed to be a response from Achilles to what his mother said to him.

Comment: Here is the full dialogue between Achilles and Thetis . "Itaque Achilles matrem suam vocavit: “Iuva me!” In mari Thetis eum audivit et ad eum cucurrit: Tuas sententias intellego, mi dulcis fili,” dixit. “Omnes Graeci te magno in honore habere debent; sine te enim Troianos vincere non possunt. Cogita haec: Si nunc hoc ex bello fugies, tibi erit parva gloria, sed vita longa; si autem hoc loco manebis, magnam gloriam invenies, sed tuam viam amittes.” “O beata mater, bonum animum habe!” dixit Achilles."

Comment: Now that i think about it, its probably more likely that this is a typo.

Comment: I don't think _habē_ is a typo but is _viam_ a typo for _vītam_? _Viam_ is not "life".

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Bonum animum habere* means "to have good courage, to be confident." This expression is used, for example,  in the plays of Plautus.

I think you are somewhat mistaken when you characterize (in the comments) Thetis' words as "motivating her son." She suggests he only has the choice between ignominy and early death, which is a bleak outlook. In that context it makes perfect sense that he would in his response try to cheer her up.

Thus I think your objections to the second person imperative should be alleviated. *Habe* is the second person singular active imperative and fits well in this context.

You will indeed find this usage in Plautus, e.g.:

> Tace, bonum habe animum, Euclio.

([Aulularia, 2,2](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0032%3Aact%3D2%3Ascene%3D2))

No doubt the authors of your exercise had that in mind. Otherwise, you could also say *bono animo sis.*

---

As a side note, Thetis was undisputably a very beautiful woman/nymph, but *beatus, -a, -um* does not mean "beautiful."

Comment: Perhaps "undisputedly a very..." or simply "indisputably beautiful..."

Comment: @rkedge In any event, it's just not advisable to question the beauty of the Nereids. Ask any Ethiopian [what happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassiopeia_(mother_of_Andromeda)) if you do it.